# Xamarin Forms BarBackground Lost on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been wrestling with an issue the past couple of days regarding the bar color on Android. The stakeholders wanted a particular shade of blue for the NavigationPage bar, and while it can be set initially using

```
   private Page GetNavigationPage(Page innerPage){
        var navigation =  new NavigationPage (innerPage);
        navigation.BarBackgroundColor= Color.FromHex ("#00263A");
        navigation.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex ("#00263A");
            return navigation;
    }
```

We found when using the Navigation.PushModalAsync method the color of the bar would turn into a light blue color as soon as the page was invoked. According to Xamarin this is intentional to reset the ActionBar per https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22237 , but attempting to use the same NavigationPage object and set the value after the modal window was gone would not update the color, regardless of how invoked.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I created is rather dirty and I plan to make something a bit more elegant but to solve this I created an action in the MainActivity

```
 ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#00263A")));
```

or whatever you want your color to be. The solution is either to pass this into your Application class, or some service to expose it to the PCL. Then as needed you can simply call this to reset the bar to be the color of your choice. 
I found calling it right after doing a

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync
```

seems to net the cleanest looking results. In my tests I didn't notice the default color appear if I did it at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Using the idea from Christopher Richmond I came up with the following rather lean workaround.

Put this somewhere at the end of your `MainActivity.OnCreate` method:

```cs
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.ModalPopping += (sender, e) => {
    ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Red.ToAndroid()));
};
```

You can replace `Color.Red` with the color of your choice and `ModalPopping` with `ModalPushing` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution for me was to insert a "blank `ToolBarItem`" in the page.

This way, it works... not the best solution, but, works. It's a bug in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: You're right: It's a bug in Xamarin.Forms. Here are two related bugzilla entries: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30166 and https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32822.

Comment: I've also had some luck creating a base style using the desired app colors. For some reason on Samsungs it likes to revert the action bar to this aqua color.

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/